# excel formula to move value in a row to column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

`Column B` needs to be moved into different columns like
[image: screen shot - before]

`B5` in one column, `B6` in another column like wise

`Row 2 -7` needs to be moved into individual columns

[image: screen shot - after]

Comment: Is the number of rows between 2 ids constant?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `B2`: `INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,4 +(ROW()-1)*7 + COLUMN()-1)` and extend it right to `H2` and down as much is you need